# Elements outside of a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Let’s say I was using a 2D array `I[NROWS][NCOLS]` as a frame for a picture.
The expression `(row<=NROWS && col <=NCOLS)` can be used to ensure that a point `I[row][col]` isn’t in front or under the frame but how do I shield from potential outcomes where the point is above or behind the frame.

Comment: The expression `(row<=NROWS && col <=NCOLS)` ***does not*** adequately test whether `I[row][col]` is out of bounds on one of the high-index sides.  Array indexes start at 0, so if your `row` is equal to `NROWS` or your `col` is equal to `NCOLS` then `I[row][col]` expresses an out-of-bounds access.  On the other hand, array indexes start at 0, so by the same token, the test to perform on the other edges is whether the index is at least zero (inclusive on that side).

Comment: Would that still apply even if I were to use a macro that replaces NROWS and NCOLS with predefined values?

Comment: It does not matter what symbols you use in your source code to represent the dimensions of the array.  The valid index values start at 0, and (therefore) do not include the dimension (number of elements).

Comment: Array indices range from 0 to N-1 where N is the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

For an array declared `I[NROWS][NCOLS]`, the valid indices `row` for the first dimension are 0 ≤ `row` < `NROWS`, and the valid indices `col` for the second dimension are 0 ≤ `col` < `NCOLS`. Therefore, `row` and `col` form a valid pair of indices if and only if `0 <= row && row < NROWS && 0 <= col && col < NCOLS`.

(This assumes `NROWS` and `NCOLS` do not change between the declaration and the test and that `rows` and `cols` have integer types.)

Comment: "valid pair of indices if and only if " --> With `NROWS > 1`, is not `I[0][NCOLS]` valid?  IOWs, I thought the limitations was more like `I[a][b]` is valid when `a*NCOLS + b < NROW*NCOLS`. (excepting index math overflow).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: There are [language lawyer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000299/is-a-two-dimensional-array-implemented-as-a-continuous-one-dimensional-array) on multidimensional array access, but OP is using `I[a][b]` as a map into an image, so, in their model, `I[0][NCOLS]` would represent a pixel outside their rectangle rather than being an attempt to access an element in the array using alternate indices.